Is projective evolution an intrinsic part of quantum mechanics?
If you want to study 1 electron, it is described by wavefunction $\psi(x, y, z, t)$ and its evolution is dictated by Schrodinger equation.
If you want to study its interaction with another electron, then you must start over: it is a 2-electron system described by a whole wavefunction $\psi'(x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2, t)$. Although you can approximate it by wave equations of individual electrons using Hartree-Fock method and Slater determinant to enforce anti-symmetry,
$
\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1, \mathbf{r}_2, t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{vmatrix}
\psi_1(\mathbf{r}_1, t) & \psi_2(\mathbf{r}_1, t) \\
\psi_1(\mathbf{r}_2, t) & \psi_2(\mathbf{r}_2, t)
\end{vmatrix}
$
yet in principle these 2 electrons are not separable and must be studied as a whole system $\psi'$.
The introduction of the concept "projective evolution" resolved a lot of my confusions when reading materials about "measurement":
"The fact that the wavefunction can evolve in two very different ways – the first through the smooth development of the Schrödinger equation, the second from the abrupt collapse after measurement – is one of the most unsettling aspects of quantum mechanics." This is quoted from a textbook by David Tong.
However, I think such logics are problematic. The wavefunction collapse (measurement) involves the interaction of the electron of study and the apparatus, which they treated as macroscopic classical objects. Since quantum mechanics is the fundamental physics, you shouldn't have to resort to classical mechanics. As I stated at the beginning, you can't separate the electron of study and what it will interact with. The correct way is to treat all of these elementary particles as a whole wavefunction.
I don't know if anyone approached the wavefunction collapse problem in that way. (In my knowledge it's very hard if by brutal force without clever arguments. I know it's already hard to computationally deal with a molecule of tens of atoms. Measurement problem involves macroscopic objects that have particle numbers at a scale of $N_A$)
A large portion of professional physicists responded to a survey that measurement problem is a pseudo-problem or it can be explained by decoherence, which I agree. But Sabine Hossenfelder says they're wrong, it's an extremely hard unsolved problem (I don't understand her point from her arguments).
My question: is projective evolution an intrinsic part of quantum mechanics or not? If it is, when should I consider the system follows unitary evolution and when projective evolution? If it is not, has anyone done some concrete calculations or arguments to study the measurement problems in the way I suggested, and debunk the concept of wavefunction collapse: everything should follow Schrodinger equation and that's all ?

It is part of orthodox quantum theory. The reason is there are experimental facts requiring projection to update quantum state of individual system, e.g. in atom spin or light polarization quantum state preparations. This does not mean there are no problems with projection; there are, as we do not have a verified exact description of when and how (in time) it happens. It is possible projection will be explained in terms of a more detailed theory as a process happening in time, like in GRW theory. Decoherence does not do this, and thus does not solve the measurement problem.

The equations of motion of classical physics describe the evolution of a measurable quantity such as the $x$ position of a particle by a variable $x(t)$. If you measure the $x$ position at time $t$ you get the value $x(t)$.
Quantum theory gives the equation of motion of a measurable quantity in terms of Hermitian operators called observables. The possible results of the measurement of an observable are its eigenvalues. In conjunction with the state of the system, a Hermitian operator with unit trace that describes past measurement results on the system in question, you can use the equations of motion to predict the expectation value of an observable: the Born rule.
In general to predict the result of an experiment on a quantum system you have to track what would happen to all of the possible values of the relevant observables: quantum interference. For an example see Section 2 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
The equations of motion of quantum theory say that if you copy information out of a system interference is suppressed: decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Under suitable circumstances decoherent systems evolve approximately like a collection of autonomous systems each of which approximately obeys the equations of motion of classical physics:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
Since this looks a bit like a collection of parallel universes this is often called the many worlds interpretation but it is just a consequence of quantum theory being applied the way that any other physical theory would be applied. You can make some approximations rather than try to work out the wavefunction of $10^{23}$ molecules but those approximations have to be consistent with the equations of motion of quantum rather than contradicting it and the decoherence literature includes many such models.
There are physicists who don't like this and want to say that there is only one universe and one kind of theory proposed is that the other universes disappear for some reason: collapse. Most textbook treatments don't explain the process by which collapse happens and given an equation of motion, which is a little odd if collapse is required to explain how the world works. Some physicists have proposed collapse models
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
These models don't currently reproduce the predictions of relativistic variants of quantum theory and those constitute the vast bulk of experimentally tested predictions of quantum theory
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Another problem with collapse models is that there is a range of measurement types that are often used by physicists that haven't been treated using collapse and aren't consistent with it such as continuous and repeated measurements
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973
As for Sabine Hossenfelder, this is one paper in which she discusses decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.12299

However, interactions with the environment — as all interactions in quantum mechanics — are unitary transformations and as such cannot in and of themselves transform pure to mixed states. This is why, in decoherence approaches one follows up on the increase of entanglement with the operation of mathematically “tracing out” (basically: summing over) that part of the system which was designated as the environment. Tracing out is usually not interpreted as a physical process but as reflecting the experimentalist’s lack of knowledge.
Since we take an instrumentalist approach, however, we do not care about interpretations. We simply note that if we want to use traces to calculate probabilities, then we need to add this procedure to the axioms. And then we will need further assumptions about just what to trace out. Indeed, the notion of entanglement itself makes no sense unless we divide up the system into at least two partitions. That decoherence does not resolve this aspect of the measurement problem has been discussed previously in more detail in [24, 25].

The partial trace problem has been discussed by Zurek and others, see Section VI D of this paper published about 20 years ago as an example:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105127
The solution proposed is not to postulate it as an axiom, contrary to what Hossenfelder wrote. The paper Hossenfelder cites by Schlosshuaer is a long review paper and she doesn't provide any indication of where in that long review paper the claimed problem is explained and I haven't found it, such are the perils of bad citation and failing to provide quotes. The paper by Kastner makes a lot of unexplained statements such as:

That is, even if it is true that the system’s only correlation with the environment is via the interaction Hamiltonian, and the environmental systems are randomly phased with respect to each other, these conditions cannot be explained from within the Everettian account: in that account, random phases are fictions.

One would expect an assertion like this to be explained with a model to provide an example of the problem, but no such model is given. Nor is any reason given why a bunch of different systems would conspire to have constant phase relations or anything else that would pose an actual problem.
